# Alternative to Snap (Editing) in QGIS/MapInfo?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, mapinfo, line, snapping

Is there any alternative to Snap (Editing) in either QGIS or MapInfo (user-made tools), or another way to do this in ArcGIS without an advanced license?[image]

Comment: I should also add I am willing to pay for a tool that will do this, but not enough for a full advanced ArcGIS license

Comment: I now realize that you are looking for an equivalent to the [**Snap (Editing)**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000) Geoprocessing tool in which case you really need to include a link to the source of your picture and probably not to use it at all.